# Modeling within-person design (items-within-person), need to account for item?

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis, fixed-effects-model, psychometrics

Apologies if this is an elementary question - within-person designs are not my forte, and I am more used to designs in the quasiexperimental econometric tradition.

I have two designs that are the same in terms of the question I am asking here, where (to use a proxy case) I'm basically asking people if they like 10 different types of fruit, where I'm randomizing things (in two different data collections) across the fruits to see if there's an effect of treatment on how they feel about the fruit:

1. Design #1: Half of the fruits, within-person, are randomly assigned to include the modified "in a pie," to see whether specifying we mean that it's a fruit pie matters for people's opinions.
2. Design #2: After the fifth fruit, they get an article talking about the harms of the fruit industry, to see whether they feel differently about fruit as a result of that knowledge.

And yes, the order of the fruits as presented on the survey is randomized across participants.

I understand (I think) that my basic modeling approach would be a mixed effect design, predicting the outcome (the person's response to the item) from the treatment. Random intercept and slope model shown below just for sake of argument.

$$
FruitFeeling = \beta_{0j}+\beta_{1j}InPie_{ij}+\varepsilon_{ij}
$$
$$
\beta_{0j} = \gamma_{00}+u_{0j}
$$
$$
\beta_{1j} = \gamma_{10}+u_{1j}
$$

However, the distribution of the outcome varies across the fruits substantially, in such a way that my econometric impulse is to include a fixed effect for the type of fruit, as below.

$$
FruitFeeling = \beta_{0j}+\beta_{1j}InPie_{ij}+\boldsymbol{\beta_2FruitType_{ij}}+\varepsilon_{ij}
$$

where $\beta_2$ is a vector of dummy variables for the different fruit types.

However, I don't think that makes sense, and there's a bug in my head telling me that this would be somehow collapsing the variance the model is working with to a point of somewhat negating the point of the within-person model (though I could be wrong). I do expect the effect of treatment varies across fruits, but I was planning on estimating this via separate one-level models for each fruit. Unfortunately, even if I am right, I don't have the expertise or language to be able to fully articulate this thought.

TL;DR: When you have a within-person design where the repeated measures do exhibit different distributions in the outcome variable, should you be accounting for the differences in the repeated measures with some kind of measure-specific fixed effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Longer answer: Maybe I am missing something but it seems to me you have several variables:

1. Fruit
2. In a pie vs. not
3. The interaction (you didn't mention this, but I'm guessing it's important).

(and then, of course, person effects)

The interaction effect is almost certainly present. E.g. apples are good plain or in a pie; rhubarb is probably preferred in pies; bananas are probably preferred *not* in pies (yeah, I know there are pies with bananas).

You mention doing a separate analysis for each fruit. That's certainly possible, and would eliminate the possibility (much less the benefit) of having fruit and the interaction as variables. But it means you have a bunch of models instead of one, and it means you can't measure the effect size or p value for fruit type and the interaction.

I don't understand what this has to do with the person effect or what you mean by "collapsing the variance".

Comment: Thank you for your response, and I appreciate your patience with my imprecision. And yes, the interaction is important, but I was somewhat worried about the cleanliness of the interpretation and the model having now 18 terms in it (9 for the mean effects of the fruits, 9 for each interaction). (explaining what I meant by "collapsing the variance" in next comment)
Frankly, if there was a high quality published analysis with the same kind of design, I'd be open to reading it - the problem is that my Googling mostly comes up with repeated measures stuff, which isn't exactly like this.

Comment: By "collapsing the variance" - I should say that I also have been thinking about this all day and it's occurred to me that this isn't any different than what I'd be doing in a panel analysis. But still, there's something that feels odd to me about it, and at least in the brief reads of some repeated measures stuff I'm finding, it doesn't seem to me that they're accounting for the observation #, which would feel like it fits the same logic if you think the distribution of the outcome just naturally changes over time.

Comment: Plus, my causal logic makes me unsure of the point given the fruit effect isn't associated with the treatment assignment, beyond perhaps increasing the precision of estimates (which I'm not discounting as a reason, but I am searching for a more substantive reason). This all said, I'm very open to someone telling me "Your instinct to include the fixed effects is correct and you are just having anxiety."